# Dual Boot- installing windows in efi mode using gpt partition

Tags: dual-boot, gpt

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04, but now I want to install Windows 10 (dual boot). At first, I have disabled CSM and then I made a partition using Ubuntu Live CD. Then I tried to install Windows but it showed an error saying the partition is not GPT format. So to make it GPT what should I do **without loss of data** in other partitions (i.e I have 4 partition- swap,ext4,efi and unallocated(ntfs))?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows installation is off-topic.

Comment: Pardon me but I want to make GPT partition in **UBUNTU**

Comment: Maybe it is GPT already. It is default for Ubuntu. I don't think you can change MBR to GPT keeping the data.

Answer (score 0):

A. Back up everything first. Everything. Really.

B. The [gdisk](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html) app  allows you to change from MBR to GPT.

C. Don't expect to be able to install Win10 without having it stomp all over your Linux install. Be prepared to reinstall Ubuntu.